# I don't have Database option (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea

guys. **I've tried to google it** and found nothing.
I need to connect Database, but i don't have option to do this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the plugin installed.

Go to settings -> plugins -> then install **Database Tools and SQL**

[image: Database Tools and SQL path]

Comment: There is no Database Tools and SQL. But there's Database Navigator and it works.
Thank you :)

Comment: glad that helped :) Please upvote / flag as valid answer if helped ! ;)

Comment: **Database Tools and SQL** plugin is available in Ultimate edition.